# Remove unwanted text from cell

Tags: google-sheets

Thanks in advance for any help.  I'm learning but stumped right now.  I would like to remove a couple of chars that appear when I add two lines of text together.

I have a simple sheets, `col1=email, col2=combined`, `col3=skills1` `col4=skills2 col5=skills3`

Col2 is populated based on the text in col3, col4, col5. I use the following line:

`={"Combined";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(B2:B)=1,"Combined",C2:C & " | " & D2:D & " | " & E2:E))}`

Problem is I get lines like this:

> |  | ITIL, Security, Windows Server, Troubleshooting, Infrastructure,

Hence I need to check to not get the | | if there is no text in a box or any combination.  Or look for | | and delete it?

Bottom line, what do I need to change in my command to do such a thing?  THANK YOU!

Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For erase last |:

```
={ "Combined";
   ARRAYFORMULA(
     IF(ROW(B2:B)=1,
       "Combined",
       C2:C & 
       left(" | ",(C2:C<>"")*(D2:D<>"")*1000)  & 
       D2:D & 
       left(" | ",((C2:C<>"")*(E2:E<>"")*(D2:D="")+(D2:D<>"")*(E2:E<>""))*1000) & 
       E2:E
     )
   )
 }
```

Comment: Thank you again!  Truly awesome.  I hope you well!

Answer (score 1):

In B1 try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(regexreplace(trim(transpose(query(transpose(if(len(C2:E10), C2:E10&" | ",)),,50000))), "\|$",))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!  Worked GREAT! :) I can learn from this too. Thank you!

Comment: One more...  how do I get rid of the training |.  If there is an entry in C but not D then I get a | at the end of the text.  The rest works. 

={"Combined";ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IF(LEN(C2:C), C2:C & " | ",) & IF(LEN(D2:D), D2:D,)))}